# Send out XMLHttpRequest on closing Firefox

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, firefox-addon, dom-events

I have a problem. I would like to send out an XML HTTP Request (XHR) from my Firefox extension so that my server will know when Firefox has been closed.

Now the problems I found are these:

**onunload:** the xmlhttprequest is aborted when Firefox is closed, preventing it from receiving any request

**onbeforeunload**: it seems to only be initiated when Firefox is restarted, and not closed!

**onclose**: the same problem as onunload.

So what should I do?

Comment: Ok apparently, onbeforeunload is fired only when you choose File >> Exit and not with the close button.

Comment: Is there a reason it needs to be an XHR? It seems like you may not need an actual response. Perhaps a polling type solution would be good enough to indicate when the browser session is done.

Comment: yes but my application is in C#, that is why i need a remote request since I am using sockets

Comment: "onunload: the xmlhttprequest is aborted when firefox is closed, preventing it from receiving any request" I think you'll find that although Firefox doesn't receive the response, your server does see the request.

Comment: No I'm afraid I didn't receive any request. i was hoping they would be something like onbeforeclose just like there is onbeforeunload

Comment: You can't really dispatch an asynchronous XMLHttpRequest when Firefox quits because it quits synchronously. I guess you could try a synchronous request...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Neil said, a synchronous XHR request would allow the request to complete fully. However if you plan to publish your addon to official Mozilla repository, synchronous XHR requests are grounds for **rejection** ([source](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/policies/reviews)).

You may also want to check out some of the [Observer Notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Observer_Notifications), specifically the ones dealing with application shutdown.  Also, if you're trying to develop a model of the browser, you may like the `user-interaction-inactive` observer notification as well. ;)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may stumble upon. I have a very simple solution to this.
I am working on a socket(-like) based project and the same problem also occurred to me.
Here is my solution:

```
function freezeScreen(ms){

    var s=(new Date).getTime();

    while(((new Date).getTime())-s<ms){}

};
```

This will force the browser window to freeze for the given amount of ms.

Just after you submit your asynchronous request make a call to freezeScreen with say 50ms. The user probably wont notice it and it gives the client enough time to send out the request before the client shuts down.